# How to generate a column in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a small challenge in excel.

Let's say I have a column called impressions and other column called cliks. I want to display the click rate on a pivot table (click rate is the ratio between clicks and impressions).

I tried (almost) everything, and unfortunately I am not being able to do it :(

[image]

---

As you can see from the image, I can manually calculate the click rate, however I am failing in do it inside the pivot table...

Comment: a calculated field using ='clicks'/'impressions' oughta work

Comment: @JosieP how exactly do "insert" a calculated field inside the pivotTable?

Comment: @JosieP i searched google for insert calculated field and got the answer, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

and this is how a calculated field is generated. Thank you JosieP, for your helpful  comment.